# Angular 4 - Fetch ID from one API and concatenate it with the URL of another API

Tags: html, angular

I'm working with Angular 4+.

I've added an API that fetches the company list. Against that company list, I'm fetching services that specific company booked.

For fetching the list of services that specific company booked I've created a function `getCompanyServices()` and called it in `ngOnInit` my API looks like this:

`www.example.com/company-service/255` where 255 is the id of the company being fetched by another api.

If I simply show `{{company.id}}` in html view it displays the id but **how do I concatenate that company.id in the API URL of get company services?**

Approaches I've tried:

1. Create a variable, company_id in my component.ts file assigned it data.company-id but the data doesn't parse.
2. Pass company id in the function where I'm calling my `getCompanyServices()` API but I'm unable to understand how to parse the data into it.

Code:
demo.service.ts (for hitting apis)

```
getCompanies() {
    return this.http.get('http://example.com/api/companies', httpOptions);
  }


  getCompanyServices() {
   
    return this.http.get('http://example.com/v1/company-service', httpOptions);
  }
```

services.component.ts file

```
    companies: any=[];
    services: any=[];

 ngOnInit() { 
    this.getCompanies();
    this.getCompanyServices();   
 }

 getCompanies() {
        this._demoService.getCompanies().subscribe(
            (response:any) => { console.log("Response =" , response);
        this.companies = response.data;
    },

            err => { console.error(err)},
            () => { console.log("ALL Companies FETCHED!") } 
        )
    }
  
  
    getCompanyServices() {
        this._demoService.getCompanyServices().subscribe(
            (response:any) => { console.log("Response =" , response);
           this.services = response.data;},

            err => { console.error(err)},
            () => { console.log("Services FETCHED!") }
        )
    }
```

HTML file

```
<p>{{company.id}}</p>
<p>{{company.name}}</p>
<button class="sidebar-services">Services</p>
```

Comment: Pls add more code to your question.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Added the code.

Comment: So, your desired url is for example `'http://example.com/v1/company-service/255`?

Comment: Yes. The practice I follow is create a testing folder like v1 and after the data is successfully integrated in app I add the api in api folder making the url example.com/api/api-name

Answer (score 0):

You may do the second call when the first will resolve to take all the companies list in your app then you can request the company  specific service information.

In ngOninit
      `this.getcountries().subscribe(data=>{
         // your stuff
          this.getCompanyServices(id) // the company id that 
      you need
         .subscribe(...`

Getcompanyservice definition

```
 `
  getCompanyServices(id)  {
    this._demoService.getCompanyServices(id).subscribe(
        (response:any) => { console.log("Response =" , response);
       this.services = response.data;},

          err => { console.error(err)},
          () => { console.log("Services FETCHED!") }
       )
    }

`
```

In the service
     `getCompanyServices(id) {

```
   return this.http.get(`http://example.com/v1/company-service/${id},  httpOptions);
  }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand from your question, what you need is to get companyId and for each companyId get its services. You can achieve it by using flatMap as below:

```
this.subsc = this._demoService.getCompanies()
.pipe(flatMap((s) => {
    this.companies.push(s);
    return s.id;
}),
flatMap((id) =>{
    return this._demoService.getCompanyServices(id).pipe(map((services) => {
        return services;
    }));
}))
.subscribe(res => {
    this.services.push(res);
}, 
undefined,
() => console.log('complete'));
```

I mimicked demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwsltm

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises, fetch the data and do another call..

if im not mistaken you can do something like that

```
this.http.get('http://example.com/api/companies', httpOptions)
      .timeout(15000)
      .map(res => res.json()) // you might not need this line
      .toPromise()
      .then(compList => {
       //here you have the company list
       console.log('compList', compList); // check your developer tools to see the list 
       this.http.get('www.example.com/company-service/' + x, httpOptions) //where x should be substituted with the id of the desired company
      }
```

If you dont want to change the implementation you already have then wrap each of the functions used with a [Promise](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/promises/) and just call the function and .then it

will become something like getCompanies().then(...

if you need me to explain more or something just comment..
Hope this helped